# Visual Studio: Real time method call trace?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

This is what I'm looking for: I'd like to be able to get a real time method call listing when I am debugging my program. So for example, say I run my program via the debugger if I press a button or do anything in my program I'd like for it to spit out, say on a visual studio plugin, in real time, all the methods it went through when I pressed this button or did some kind of user action with my program.

I actually once wrote a visual studio plugin that does that by using the visual studio profiler api (I had to write a c++ com server dll that receives this information and pipes it back into my c# plugin). I did this a few years back and I have no idea where I put it. But I'm wondering if Microsoft did something like this in visual studio 2010 or if you know of any third party plugins like this because it is a very handy debugging utility.

Thanks

Comment: IntelliTrace is only available in ultimate. I'm working on VS2010 professional. argh.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Visual Studio 2010's Intellitrace feature - it might get you what you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should check IntelliTrace debugging in Visual Studio 2010. It works only with x86 though

Answer (score 0):

It's not free, it's not even cheap, but [RedGate's ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) can provide that data and more.

Comment: I used ants in the past, but I don't think it supports REAL TIME method call invocations.

Comment: ah, my misunderstanding, you are correct it is not *real time*.  Wonder if anyone's built anything around PostSharp ... a quick google doesn't reveal any though.

Comment: @Schnitzel, as soon as you attach tools like this, Real Time stops being Real.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve that using AOP, e.g. [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp) and an implementation of it's [OnMethodBoundaryAspect](http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/2.0/Default.aspx##PostSharp.chm/html/T_PostSharp_Aspects_OnMethodBoundaryAspect.htm) and a [MultiCastAttribute](http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/2.0/Default.aspx##PostSharp.chm/html/1B05CE59-61DE-4043-8E7C-12C130B1ACBB.htm) to apply your aspect to every method of your program. They even have an [example](http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/2.0/Default.aspx##PostSharp.chm/html/1B05CE59-61DE-4043-8E7C-12C130B1ACBB.htm) for something quite similar to what you want on their site.

Answer (score 0):

Updated link as of 8/15/2018: [IntelliTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/intellitrace)

***Note that this feature is in Enterprise edition only***

From the linked page:

> You can spend less time debugging your application when you use
>   IntelliTrace to record and trace your code's execution history. You
>   can find bugs easily because IntelliTrace lets you:

- > Record specific events
- > Examine related code, data that appears in the Locals window during debugger events, and function call information
- > Debug errors that are hard to reproduce or that happen in deployment

> **You can use IntelliTrace in Visual Studio Enterprise edition (but not
>   the Professional or Community editions)**.

Answer (score 0):

My [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) extension shows method call listing when you press a button or do anything in a program. It works outside Visual Studio debugger.